# How to forecast with a regression model with ARIMA errors?

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, dynamic-regression

I have obtained the following coefficients after using the auto.arima function in R:

$y_t = 0.87 x_t - 0.51x_{t-1} + n_t$
where $n_t = 0.83n_{t-1} + e_t$

My question is, how to obtain $\hat{n}_{t-1}$ which I will use to forecast $n_t$?

I tried $\hat{n}_{t-1} =y_{t-1} - (0.87 x_{t-1} - 0.51x_{t-2})$ but the forecast values I obtain with this equation differ from the fitted values outputted by R, so I am doing something wrong.

I have to do the forecast with the obtained coefficients in Excel (the forecast is for someone who does not use R and wants to do the forecast every week as new data comes in).

Thank you!

Comment: It looks OK to me, I cannot see the mistake. Was there perhaps an intercept in the model that you forgot to account for?